# Give a GET value to a javascript Pop Up

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently working on a page which loops some content. When you click on the image, more information appears in a javascript popup. I want to give every popup an unique link (with a $_GET). Any ideas how I can do this with PHP or Javascript (or both).

Pop-up script:

```
<!----- JAVASCRIPT FOR EACH ELEMENT ---->
<script type="application/javascript">
  function openPopup<?php echo $persona->{'User ID'}; ?>() {
      document.getElementById('<?php echo $persona->{'User ID'}; ?>').style.display = "block";
  }
  function closePopup<?php echo $persona->{'User ID'}; ?>() {
      document.getElementById('<?php echo $persona->{'User ID'}; ?>').style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

The pop-ups are created inside a foreach loop (PHP) with the onClicks in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want, that your popup pops up automatically when the page with a given GET parameter is loaded? :-)

Comment: don't mix php and js - it's bad practice, use a hidden input with a data-value attribute

Comment: Yes, exactly! :)

Comment: @Elosias where is the `$_GET` param in you example? Also you can manipulate the `GET` in `javascript`... you don't need to inject the `php` into `javascript` code you can take @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs example with the hidden inputs or with an `ajax` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['my_get_var']) && !empty($_GET['my_get_var']) : ?>
    <div class="my-popup">
        <!-- my popup code -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

no need for js at all - just CSS, HTML and PHP